# Make optional property required in some cases

Tags: typescript

I have a type that has an optional property, but in some cases, I know it should exist.  How do I make the property non-optional in those cases?

For example, given a type that represents a JSON response -

```
type Response = {
   id: string
   users?: User[]
   // ... other properties, some optional
}
```

I have a case where if I pass a certain query param to the API, I am expecting `users` to be fulfilled, and given I know *when* this occurs, I would like my response type to define that `users` is no longer optional.

Im using `react-query`, so -

```
const { data } = useQuery(
    ['businesses'],
    async (): Promise<Response> => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
        params: queryParams,
      });

      return data;
    }
  );
```

In the above, `data.users` is possibly undefined.  What is the best way to say that `user` is not optional in this particular case.

Ive tried updating `Response` to -

```
type Response<Users = undefined> = {
   id: string
   users: Users
   // ... other properties, some optional
}
```

note, `users` is no longer optional (`?`), rather it is defaulted to `undefined` (slightly different..)

and then using -

```
 Promise<Response<User[]>>
```

for when I expect `users` to exist, else -

```
Promise<Response>
```

when it *may not* exist.

Is there a better way?  It feels strange that I have the caller define the return type of the `users` property, rather than in some way say that it just 'expects' `users` to exist but lets `Response` internally define what the type is, i.e. `User[]`.

Comment: I am afraid I do not fully get the point? Why do you need to have a second type with mandatory `users`?

But if you need to do this, you may try the following:

```
interface Response {
   id: string,
   users?: User[]
}
...

interface Response2 extends Response {
  users: User[]

```

Comment: because the API im working against accepts an optional query param `?users=true` that will add the `users` array to response (dont shoot me, I didnt define the API contract :D ) (also, its updating the existing `Response` type, not creating a new type.  But thanks for the idea, I'll give that a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) could be useful to you -

```
const { data } = useQuery(
  ['businesses'],
  async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get<Required<Response>>(url, {
      params: queryParams,
    })
    return data
  }
);

// typeof data: undefined | {id: string; Users: User[] }
```

Verify on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoEU4DMoQhwBEUApsgMYwC0AjgK5lQCexAUKJLCgB7AR0+QiWT9BHdjBZgycAKqpmcALxwA3gF92UmXIxlUkAHZLVG9nDjAAJgC44qGFGDGA5pYVKoqAPwPFZgBtAF12bXZKCFN4BigAG3NiSSiYuEZmFgAFZChkEHQ1LR1Upw04G2QYZDhNc2wAOgYlLCZWAApPIIByACNm10MlVG6QgBpPNBZjSjh2gEpVAD4LKytS+HUKqpq6tWQAd2RgeDEBVAa3MhgAHgNGYHIbO8MTJSWl9rj4sdW1qzAuXyqAcGVYOTyBQm-00808VnIMDixm21U82nmAG4dAB6HGo5AOBjGGxkXCDGxwAA+5VsDicLncmK8zBBLKgoVqOmAuDmlWqi3UnlKEHiZAa8Qgbna-OQDUCPkWeLgAW8qFC4XYQA).

---

If you have a *selection* of fields you would like to make required, we can use a combination of [Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype), [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys), and [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) -

```
Omit<Response, "Users"> & Required<Pick<Response, "Users">>
```

Writing this each time you need it would be a pain. Write your own `Require` helper -

```
type Require<T, K extends keyof T> = 
  Omit<T, K> & Required<Pick<T, K>>
```

```
const { data } = RQ.useQuery(
  ['businesses'],
  async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get<Require<Response, "Users">>(url, {
      params: queryParams,
    })
    return data
  }
);
```

If you have multiple fields you want to require, you can use

```
Require<Response, "Users" | "Foo" | "Bar">
```

Verify on [typecript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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-M-QHSkuuhxxRLJUlvDNZnN5pPIQFpKDNsuOZwh-2emze325dhAA).

Comment: I think this would work, if I didnt have other optional properties on `Response`

Comment: thanks Andy, I made an update with the new criteria

Comment: This works perfect, thanks!